# Operations in background with UI reaction

Tags: c#, user-interface, freeze

I need to make a sorting application that displays the current operations.
I've done it like that:

I have collection of `int`s. Inside it, I have sorting algorithms and event 'step' that takes two arguments 'operation' eg. compare, permutation etc. and `int[]` of elements that I do something with.

I want to change the item background in `ListView` if sorting is doing something with specific items. '250 ms blink'. Something like that:

```
listView1.Items[1].BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
listView1.Items[2].BackColor = Color.LightGreen;

Thread.Sleep(250);

for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
{
    listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

But when I'm trying to start sorting, the UI is freezing and after couple of seconds it is displayed as a `SortedCollection`.

My question is:
How do I show 'live' actions on UI during sorting?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Explain why you use Thread.Sleep.

Comment: To give a chance for user to see that color change. Then color backs to white. This code it's just little fragment of all code. That is where I think is my problem.

Comment: If this is Windows Forms then you can call Application.DoEvents.  If it's WPF you should implement this with an animation in a style.

Comment: @hoodaticus that works! Thanks! :)

Comment: I improved some grammar in an attempt to make the (already successfully answered) question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Thread.Sleep(250)` use `await Task.Delay(250)`. To make this possible you need to mark your method as `async`

Comment: I was trying this, but i'm not sure which method should I make async. Sorting method inside collection with event invoking? Method that starts sorting in UI class eg. method(){ collection.QuickSort() } ? Maybe I didn't try all option. Can you be more precise at which stage should I make async method?

Comment: Change all methods in call hierarchy to return `async Task`, then await them in upper method, instead of the last one (probably button click event)-that should return `async void`

Comment: I found the way already but thank anyway. I'm sure that will be useful for me in the future. :)